# Interface NodeMCU with RCWL-0516 Microwave Radar Sensor and power via battery

Tags: arduino, esp8266, proximity-sensor, nodemcu

I am trying to interface NodeMCU with RCWL-0516 Microwave Radar Sensor and power it via battery. Below is the circuit diagram

[image]

Below is the Arduino Code I am using :

```
int Status = 12;  // Digital pin D6

int sensor = A0;  // Analog pin A0

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(115200);
   pinMode(sensor, INPUT);   // declare sensor as input
   pinMode(Status, OUTPUT);  // declare LED as output

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeat edly:
    long state = analogRead(sensor);
    Serial.println(state);
    if(state >= 200) {
      digitalWrite (Status, HIGH);
      //Serial.println(state);
      Serial.println("Motion detected!");
      delay(1000);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite (Status, LOW);
      //Serial.println(state);
      Serial.println("Motion absent!");
      delay(1000);
      }

}
```

Now with this circuit I am facing following issues :

1) Radar Sensor keep getting triggered and the led keeps getting on and off
(When I replace radar sensor with PIR HC-sr501 sensor it starts working normally. I suspect there is some interference between NodeMCU wifi signal and doppler wave)

2) No matter if I use PIR Sensor or radar sensor the battery last for only few hours and after it goes below 5.5V sensors stop working.

So, how can I make radar sensor and NodeMCU work together with battery without false triggering and how can I make it work for 2-3 days without changing battery?

**UPDATE**

When I power NodeMCU with USB then radar sensor is working fine. (So I don't think there is interference of NodeMCU with Microwave Sensor). Below is the circuit digram with NodeMCU powered by USB. Why there is constant trigger when NodeMCU is powered by battery?

[image]

[Link of data-sheet of Radar Sensor](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_rcwl-0516.pdf)

Comment: Without a full data sheet for the radar sensior this is unanswerable and will probably have to be closed.  You code shows no effort to reduce power consumption and only operate when needed, so even apart from the sensor the constant power consumption on the MCU should be expected to result in short battery life.  Creating battery powered systems is practucally hard even for the experienced, you do not seem to have given power conservation any thought.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Data sheet added. BTW, RCWL-0516 is very well known sensor and its data-sheet can be easily found.

Comment: While better than nothing, that is *not* a data sheet, it's a writeup of some other hobbyist's *reverse engineering* effort.  Critically, **it has no statement of transmit or idle power consumption**.   It seems your problem may be power related, 9v radio batteries are notoriously weak, so perhaps try 5 or 6 alkaline AA cells.  But the issue remains that you cannot expect reasonable battery life without careful engineering to make your project sleep in a micramp current range and only wake up occasionally to take a measurement.  That is far too broad a topic to cover here.

Comment: At a basic level, you might ask: do you see many battery powered microwave motion detectors being offered for sale?  If not, there is probably a reason, such as that it's not really a combination which works well.  And even if it is possible with some devices, there's no indication that your sensor is designed for battery power, that it has a way to put it in a suspend mode, or that it will work very well if you use a power switch chip to turn it on briefly before turning it back off again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton when I power NodeMCU with USB, still radar sensor is powered by battery but its working ok.

Comment: We could keep chipping away at the various mistakes being made - for example, *you are inexplicably trying to read a digital signal as an analog one* - but the reality is that **this project will probably never have decent battery life unless it receives some very advanced re-engineering**.  You should either stick with mains power, or pick a more practical project to work on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton according to the second circuit if I use a power bank and power NodeMCU with USB then Project will work on battery (, but two separate battery). I am just curious,  why Radar sensor and NodeMCU is not working correctly with same battery where as PIR sensor and NodeMCU is working ok with same battery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Power Bank for Power supply via USB and following the below circuit resolved the issue

[image]

Comment: It won't work for very long on a powerbank - the whole idea remains relatively impractical and useless.

Comment: Whether it will work long or not depends on the type of power bank in use. Without knowing that you shouldn't come to conclusion and vote down the answer @Chris

Comment: Wrong again - no power bank will run it all that long.  **What you have is fundamentally not engineered for battery power**.  Fix that, don't throw a huge battery at it just to get a week.